# Factory waiting for a Future to construct the object

Tags: dart, firebase

How can I make this Future inside the Factory synchronous? I'm returning null here to the client.

```
  factory Project.retrieve(String hash, CompetencesService service) {
    Project project;
    service.dbRef.child("project").once("value").then((snapshot) {
      Map val = snapshot.val();
      project = toObservable(new Project.fromJson(val));

      if(project != null) {
        project.listen(service);
        print("listening1");
      } else {
        project = toObservable(new Project.newHash(hash));
        service.dbRef.child("project").update(project.toJson()).then((error) {
          if(error) {
            //
          } else {
            project.listen(service);
            print("listening2");
          }
        });
      }
    });
    return project;
  }
```

Somebody [asked](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/23115) for this, but I'm looking for examples of workarounds.

Comment: In the end, I went with a solution that avoided this alltogether. Instead of trying to substitute the entire `project` object, I went for substituting parts of the object. I changed `Project.fromJson()` from a factory to a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment there is no way to create asynchronous constructors or factories, as well as synchronously wait for a `Future`.

The latter is for an obvious reason: if you will stop and wait synchronously for something dependent from current isolate itself (not external event like file i/o), it will never happen, as `Isolate` is in a single thread which is stopped in a wait state.

So, the only way here is to have static method returning a `Future` with `Project` instance, like the one mentioned in a link you provided:

```
static Future<Project> retrieve() async {
  var snapshot = await service.dbRef.child("project").once("value");
  Project project = toObservable(new Project.fromJson(snapshot.val()));

  ...

  return project; // Note you're actually returning a Future here
}
```

Comment: One disadvantage is that this can move the problem up a level.

Answer (score 0):

I try to implements `Future` interface, then factory & constructor could return a `Future` and able to be `await`.

```
@proxy
class AsyncFact implements Future {
  factory AsyncFact() {
    return new AsyncFact._internal(new Future.delayed(
        const Duration(seconds: 1), () => '[Expensive Instance]'));
  }

  AsyncFact._internal(o) : _mirror = reflect(o);

  final InstanceMirror _mirror;
  @override
  noSuchMethod(Invocation invocation) => _mirror.delegate(invocation);
}

@proxy
class AsyncConst implements Future {
  AsyncConst() : _mirror = reflect(new Future.delayed(
          const Duration(seconds: 1), () => '[Expensive Instance]'));

  final InstanceMirror _mirror;
  @override
  noSuchMethod(Invocation invocation) => _mirror.delegate(invocation);
}

main() async {
  print(await new AsyncFact()); // [Expensive Instance]
  print(await new AsyncConst()); // [Expensive Instance]
}
```

Comment: Isn't this just a more general example of @Mike's answer?

Comment: This example achieve approximate async factory / constructor feature, not just only async static factory method.

Comment: For me,  this is the same as constructor in a Future generic class in a way its not a class we need to implement, but its future.